# How to create an apt-mirror for Ubuntu 20.04 and raspbian using apt-mirror and nginx

Tags: nginx, apt-mirror

I want to create an apt-mirror for Ubuntu 20.04 and Raspbian using apt-mirror and nginx. I also use an external hard drive.

What I realize is that I need two ports for nginx and I ran apt-mirror twice in a row to download the packages from Ubuntu 20.04 and Raspbian into two different directories.

On another computer with Internet connection I edited at first the /etc/apt/mirror.list like this:

```
...
set base_path /mnt/ubuntu

deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted univer>
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

clean http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
...
```

Then I run sudo apt-mirror

After that I changed it to:

```
...
set base_path /mnt/raspbian
deb-armhf http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi 
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi

clean http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian
```

...

Of course sudo apt-mirror again.

On the "server" without internet connection I mounted my external hard drive. My /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
UUID=XXXXXXXXXX /mnt ntfs defaults 0 0
/mnt /var/www/html/apt none bind 0 0
```

After that I run sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/apt

Then I created the /etc/nginx/sites-available/ubuntu-mirror file and created a symbolic link to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ubuntu-mirror.

The file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 81;
    server_name pasnas.local;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/apt/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

For the raspbian-mirror it looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 82;
    server_name pasnas.local;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/apt/raspbian;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I should use www/html/apt/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu here yet. So for raspbian I also tried the following different root directories: www/html/apt/raspbian, www/html/apt/raspbian/mirror/archive.raspbian.org or www/html/apt/raspbian/mirror/archive.raspbian.org/raspbian.

What should be the right root path for both?

On the Clients I changed the /etc/apt/sources.list and added following. For Ubuntu 20.04 I added:

```
deb http://pasnas.local:81/ubuntu focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://pasnas.local:81/ubuntu focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://pasnas.local:81/ubuntu focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://pasnas.local:81/ubuntu focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

I am not sure if http://pasnas.local:81/ubuntu/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ or http://pasnas.local:81/ubuntu/

On the Raspberry Pi I added:

```
deb http://pasnas.local:82/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

Of course I run sudo apt update. But it will not work.

Sure, I have configured the directory back and forth. It didn't really work. Do you see any errors that I don't? Did I leave out any steps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Despite the fact that you post a lot details, your question is essentially "It will not work" without an actual error message clarifying what doesn't work. (note that you can always check in your web server logs to see what requests get made to your web server and if they fail, for what reason when apt complains about 404 and permission denied errors) Also I fail to see why you think you need two different ports in nginx, most people set up a single host (and if necessary non-standard port) that exports a directory single structure `mirror/ubuntu` `mirror/raspian` , `mirror/debian` etc. etc.